# Display more than one images from drawable folder to view default imageviewer in android

Tags: android

i want to display more than one images in android default imageviewer.i am view one image from sdcard to default android imageviewer.i want to display more than one images from drawable folder if it's not possible or how to view images from sdcard folder like if images folder contain more than one images to view all images in default imageview in android.

here's code for view image from sdcard to android default image viewer:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/slide-4.jpg"), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

i want to show more than images from drawable folder or any sdcard folder or assets folder can help me greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!